# How to find maximum value of the function $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2+x^2y^2$ and $\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=?$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, maxima-minima, exterior-derivative

How to find maximum of the function $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2+x^2y^2$ ,$(x,y)\in \overline{B_2}(0) $ (closed ball of radius $2$)

The unique critical point is $(0,0)$ but is not $max(u)$. I've tried to use polar coordinates but without result.

Ok second part...Let's say we found $max(u)=(x_0,y_0)$. We have to calculate
$\cfrac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}(x_0,y_0)$ (exterior normal derivative of $u  $ in $(x_0,y_0)$   ) 
and this is $\nabla u(x_0,y_0)\cdot\nu=(2x_0+2y_0^2 x_0,-2y_0+2x_0^2 y_0) \cdot\nu(x_0,y_0)$  but how to fin $\nu.$ It would be useful for me to see how do we find $\nu.$

Comment: The function continuous on a compact always reaches its maximum value. Use the Lagrange multiplier method. On the second question - you must first find the normal vector.

Comment: Check the critical points, then check all of the points on the boundary of the ball. Do this by maximising on the boundary of the ball by setting $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ and optimising as a function of $x$.

Comment: I edited the question.Understud first part but second...

Comment: If $\nu $ is perpedicular to $\nabla u(x_0,y_0)$ then  exterior derivative :$\nabla u(x_0,y_0)\cdot \nu=0$ is this ok?

Comment: Let me prove without Analysis that the maximum is $5$: Note that the maximum is obtained at the boundary so $x^2=4-y^2$. Hence we have $$u(x,y)\le 5\iff x^2\cdot(1+y^2)\le5+y^2\iff (4-y^2)\cdot(1+y^2)\le5+y^2\iff(y^2-1)^2\ge 0$$ which is always true. We have equality if and only if $y^2=1$ so the maximum is obtained at the four points $y=\pm1,x=\pm\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst I think it should be $x^2+y^2=4$

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: ok ok but how about $\partial u/\partial \nu$

Comment: @IceSandu The outward unit normal of a circle at the point $(x,y)$ on that circle is $$\nu(x,y)=\frac{(x,y)}{\|(x,y)\|}=\frac{(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ Now use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1235463/). Also note that in our case $$\|(x,y)\|=2$$ because we have a circle of radius $2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have
$$\nabla u(x,y)=\bigl(2x(y^2+1),2y(x^2-1)\bigr)\ ,\tag{1}$$
and it is easy to check that $(0,0)$ is the only critical point in the interior of $B_2$, and $u(0,0)=0$. In order to deal with the boundary $\partial B_2$ we use the parametrization
$$\partial B_2:\quad\phi\mapsto\bigl(x(\phi),y(\phi)\bigr)=(2\cos\phi,2\sin\phi)\qquad\bigl(\phi\in{\mathbb R}/(2\pi)\bigr)$$
and then have to analyze the pullback $$f(\phi):=u\bigl(x(\phi),y(\phi)\bigr)=4\cos^2\phi-4\sin^2\phi+16\cos^2\phi\sin^2\phi\ .$$ We obtain
$$f(\phi) =24\cos^2\phi-16\cos^4\phi-4\tag{2}$$
and then
$$f'(\phi)=-16\cos\phi\sin\phi(3-4\cos^2\phi)\ .$$
There are eight zeros of $f'$, coming from the equations $\cos\phi=0$, $\>\sin\phi=0$, $\>\cos\phi=\pm{\sqrt{3}\over2}$. This means that the function $f$ defined in $(2)$ has eight critical points. You have to compute the value of $f$ in all of these points, and to select the largest of these values, if it is $>0$. Otherwise the maximum of $u$ is at the origin.

It seems that, e.g.,  for $\phi={\pi\over6}$ we have a maximum. Hence we consider the point $$(x_0,y_0):=\bigl(2\cos{\pi\over6},2\sin{\pi\over6}\bigr)=\bigl(\sqrt{3},1\bigr)\ .$$
Using $(1)$ we find
$$\nabla u(x_0,y_0)=\bigl(4\sqrt{3},4\bigr)\ .$$
Since $\partial B_2$ is a circle centered at the origin the unit normal $\nu$ at $(x_0,y_0)$ is nothing else but
$$\nu=\left(\cos{\pi\over6},\sin{\pi\over6}\right)=\left({\sqrt{3}\over2},{1\over2}\right)\ .$$
Therefore we obtain
$${\partial u\over\partial \nu}(x_0,y_0)=\langle\,\nabla u(x_0,y_0), \>\nu\,\rangle=4\sqrt{3}\cdot {\sqrt{3}\over2}+4\cdot {1\over2}=8\ .$$

Answer (score 1):

First we take the partial derivatives with respect to the variables x and y and set them equal to zero:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac {\partial  }{\partial x}&=2x+2xy^2=0  \\
\frac {\partial  }{\partial y}&=-2y+2x^2=0
\end{align}
$$

From the second equation, we have either: $y=0$ or $x=\pm 1$. Now we substitute each value into the first equation to get the corresponding variable: for =0, we get =0, while for =1 we have no real solutions and for x=-1 again no real solutions, so we discard these two.

Note that (0,0) satisfies our constraint $={(,):^2+^2≤4}$. So we evaluate (0,0) which gives us =0.

Now lets have a look as the perimeter of the closed disk of radius 2. On this disk, we have $^2=4−^2$, so we substitute this into the original function to get:

$=^2-y^2+x^2y^2=x^2-4+x^2+4x^2-x^4=-x^4+6x^2-4=0$

We set $/=0$ to get $=0$ or $x=\pm \sqrt 3$ and we evaluate $$ at these two point to get $f=-4$ and $f=5$ respectively.

Finally we have to check the extreme values of  on the disk: =−2 and =2, which give us =4 respectively.

So only stationary point is at (0,0) and in fact it is a saddle point.

Alternatively you can use the Langrange multipliers method with ∇(,)=λ∇g(,) where g(x,y) is the constraint on the disk.

Comment: https://portal.uea.ac.uk/documents/6207125/15697826/Stationary+Points+of+Functions+of+Two+Variables.pdf/558eefb7-01ff-43f0-a444-f8acc261a1b0 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1708594/find-the-stationary-points-of-fx-y-z-xyyzxz-subject-to-the-constraint-x

Comment: +1 for your answer. For the $\pm 1$ use the mathjax code \pm 1